# SSIS process finished before ending merge join

Tags: join, merge, ssis

I am trying to do a merge join between two datasources in SSIS and save it in a flat file. However, when I run it the process ends before the merge join does (or so it seems).

The three files are created with data, but the "VY" one is not what was expected: it should have all columns from Query A but one, and one column from Query B.

The merge join is set between two columns.

Here I leave a picture of the result:
[image: Data flow pipeline]

EDIT:
To explain the configuration in more detail, here is a pic of the merge settings: I want to join the output from multicast with the output from multicast 1 on Col 1.1 - Col 2.1 and Col 1.3 - Col 2.3. Also, I want to get all columns from the left except Col 1.5, and from the right get  Col 2.2.
[Merge join settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDgaf.png)

Files LV and VK are filled with data, but not VY.

Comment: What does the VY file contain and how is the Merge join configured.  The image looks odd, but it's also working with no rows - not sure if that is affecting it.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I just added some more information of the merge join settings.

Comment: Could you make sure there are no differences on the join columns - trim spaces and force them to be all upper or lower case?